# collect the order of the <span>-elements

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on a code in which the user changes the span element order as he wishes.
I need to collect the order of the span elements and put it in a variable for example, if the order look as below:

```
<span id="span-2">[<a class="move-up">Up</a>/<a class="move-down">Down</a>]</span>
<span id="span-3">[<a class="move-up">Up</a>/<a class="move-down">Down</a>]</span>
<span id="span-5">[<a class="move-up">Up</a>/<a class="move-down">Down</a>]</span>
<span id="span-4">[<a class="move-up">Up</a>/<a class="move-down">Down</a>]</span>
<span id="span-1">[<a class="move-up">Up</a>/<a class="move-down">Down</a>]</span>
```

then, the variable will be "2,3,5,4,1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is an identifiable parent you could do this:

```
var order = new Array();
$("#parentID span").each(function(){
    order.push($(this).attr('id').substring(5));
});
```

However, if I would try this I would add some `class`es and `data-id`s to the mix:

HTML:

```
<span class="mySpan" data-id="2" id="span-2">[<a class="move-up">Up</a>/<a class="move-down">Down</a>]</span>
<span class="mySpan" data-id="3" id="span-3">[<a class="move-up">Up</a>/<a class="move-down">Down</a>]</span>
<span class="mySpan" data-id="5" id="span-5">[<a class="move-up">Up</a>/<a class="move-down">Down</a>]</span>
<span class="mySpan" data-id="4" id="span-4">[<a class="move-up">Up</a>/<a class="move-down">Down</a>]</span>
<span class="mySpan" data-id="1" id="span-1">[<a class="move-up">Up</a>/<a class="move-down">Down</a>]</span>
```

JS:

```
var order = new Array();
$(".mySpan").each(function(){
    order.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
});
```

Comment: why are you doing substring(5)?

Comment: Because the OP wants only the integer portion of the id (if I understood him correctly)

Answer (score 2):

```
var ids = [];
$("span").each(function(index) {
    ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

And you will have ids in array *ids*.
For your example, it would be *ids* = ["span-2", "span-3", "span-5", "span-4", "span-1"]

Answer (score 1):

For getting the spans themselves:

```
var spanArray = []; //Contain all spans in the proper order (2,3,5,4,1)

$("span").each(function(i){
     spanArray.push($("span")[i]);
     console.log(i + ": " + this.id);
});
```

For getting only the span ids:

```
var spanIDsArray = []; //Contain all span ids in the proper order (2,3,5,4,1)

$("span").each(function(i){
     spanIDsArray.push(this.id);
     console.log(i + ": " + this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Your variable will be look like this:

$(document).ready(function(){
 var spnArray = [];
 $("span").each(function(i)
 {
    spnArray.push($(this).attr("id"));
             });
                 console.log(spnArray);
    });
```

**See DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/KcRTm/